# Rails 4:Error in setting up SignIn Page as root page using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise Gem for authentication but for the index/root page for my application I want to use sign_in page of devise gem.

I have used the following code in the config/routes.rb file

```
root  'devise/sessions#new'
```

I am getting the following error

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Here is snapshot of my rake routes output

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)             devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)               devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)              devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                 devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                      devise/registrations#destro
  workout_schedules_find POST   /workout_schedules/find(.:format)     workout_schedules#find
       workout_schedules GET    /workout_schedules(.:format)          workout_schedules#index
                         POST   /workout_schedules(.:format)          workout_schedules#create
    new_workout_schedule GET    /workout_schedules/new(.:format)      workout_schedules#new
   edit_workout_schedule GET    /workout_schedules/:id/edit(.:format) workout_schedules#edit
        workout_schedule GET    /workout_schedules/:id(.:format)      workout_schedules#show
                         PATCH  /workout_schedules/:id(.:format)      workout_schedules#update
                         PUT    /workout_schedules/:id(.:format)      workout_schedules#update
                         DELETE /workout_schedules/:id(.:format)      workout_schedules#destroy
```

Comment: use in you default controller something like `before_action :authenticate_user!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set your route file like this:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'home#dashboard', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

Devise provides some inbuilt methods like `authenticated`, `unauthenticated` etc. So as per your requirement, you can set different `root` for logged in users and non-logged in users.
`:as` will create custom named url helpers like `authenticated_root_path` and `unauthenticated_root_path`

If you will run `rake routes`, you will get:

```
   authenticated_root GET      /                             home#dashboard
 unauthenticated_root GET      /                             devise/sessions#new
```

Comment: thanks it worked !! Can you please explain the code . . what exactly devise_scope does ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working example of how to solve this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # This is the fix.
  devise_for :users, skip: :all

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/users/sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
    post "/users/sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
    delete "/users/sign_out", to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
    get "/users/password/new", to: "devise/passwords#new", as: :new_user_password
    get "/users/password/edit", to: "devise/passwords#edit", as: :edit_user_password

    patch "/users/password", to: "devise/passwords#update", as: :user_password
    put "/users/password", to: "devise/passwords#update"
    post "/users/password", to: "devise/passwords#create"

    get "/users/cancel", to: "devise/registrations#cancel", as: :cancel_user_registration
    get "/users/sign_up", to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :new_user_registration
    get "/users/edit", to: "devise/registrations#edit", as: :edit_user_registration

    patch "/users", to: "devise/registrations#update", as: :user_registration
    put "/users", to: "devise/registrations#update"
    delete "/users", to: "devise/registrations#destroy"
    post "/users", to: "devise/registrations#create"
  end
end
```